# elasticsearch, function_score SearchPhaseExecutionException

Tags: elasticsearch

I followed the tutorial at the last part of this [page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html).

```
POST /merchantindex/_search
{
    "function_score": {
    "query": {
    {"query_string": { "query": "test"}}
    },
    "functions": [
        {
            "script_score": 
            {
                "script": "return _score;"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

What I am expecting the returning of relevance score. I wanted to do some processing with the _score, e.g. _score * some other stuffs but I am just trying if the code works for now.

Error that I got is

```
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;...
```

typically means that the formatting of your query is wrong.

if you check your query you'll see that you have two curly brackets between `query` and `query_string`:

```
"query": {    {"query_string":
```

Also `function_score` needs to sit inside a query and `functions` needs to be inside `function_score`.

Try this instead:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/merchantindex/_search" -d '
{
    "query": {
      "function_score" : {
         "query" :{
            "query_string": { "query": "test"}
         },
         "functions": [
         {
            "script_score": {
                "script": "return _score;"
            }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}'
```

Comment: I actually followed the code from some site, and I have tested your version and it is not functioning as well (same error). =(. Please advise.

Comment: How have you defined your script return_score?  Can you add your full error message to your question?